# How to lock a cell after 24 hours of no editing?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, locking

When row 3 is entered, all rows before that should get locked and a 24 hours countdown timer should start as the value F3 is being entered.

When some edit is made to F3 before 24 hours, the timer has to reset to another 24 hours and after 24 hours rows, 1-3 have to get locked.

Similarly, if a new row is added (say row 4), then the same logic needs to be applied (row 4 will get locked after no edits have been made to F4 for 24 hours). Not sure how to add the timing logic to my below code.

```
     A  B   C   D   E   F
 1  A1  B1  C1  D1  E1  F1
 2  A2  B2  C2  D2  E2  F2
 3  A3  B3  C3  D3  E3  F3
```

Code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 

function lockRanges() {
 var row = 2;
 var col = 1;

 // Get last row with data in sheet
 var lastbutBeforeRow = sheet.getLastRow()-1;
 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

 //Loop until last row in sheet is passed
 while(row <= lastbutBeforeRow){
    //Lock current cell
    lockRange(row, col);
    row = row + 1;
 }
}

function lockRange(row, col){
  var range = sheet.getRange(row, col)
  var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Protected, row ' + row);
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  protection.addEditor(me);
  protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
  if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
    protection.setDomainEdit(false);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. When there are 4 rows, when "F3" is edited and "F4" is edited, the rows 1 to 3 are locked. But the countdown timer is continue to run by "F3" and "F4", in this case, I cannot understand about the logic for your goal. Can I ask you about more detail sample situations?

Comment: @Tanaike: Thank you for the response. At an instance, only the last cell of the last row will be edited. Previous row would not get edited. Hope it answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill.  Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot still understand about the logic for achieving your goal.

Comment: @user3447653 It's still not super clear what you're asking - can you edit your question and provide a step-by-step workflow?